# Limit the rate of emails sent with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am creating a forum with Laravel and as soon as a new private message or a new message in a thread where the user has participated, an email is sent. However, I have a problem: if a user receives 60 private message within an hour then he will receive 60 private message to notify him that he has a new message.

Is it possible to limit the number of emails sent per hour for example ? Is there a attribute to change somewhere ?

Here is an example of the function to find the recipient + send the private message in the `MessagesController`:

```
public function newPrivateMessage(Thread $thread, $urlToAccess){
        /* We retrieve the ID of the person connected */
        $userId = Auth::id();//auth()->user()->id
        /* We get the other user from the discussion. */
        $user = $thread->participants->where('user_id', '<>', $userId)->first();
        $userName = User::find($user->user_id);
        /* For the recipient, send an email */
        Mail::to($userName->email)->send(new NewPrivateMessageMail($user,$urlToAccess));
    }
```

And I've created a `NewPrivateMessage` inside my `http` folder with this artisan command `php artisan make:mail NewPrivateMessage`.

````
public function __construct($user,$urlToAccess)
{
    $this->data = $user;
    $this->url = $urlToAccess;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this
       ->subject('New private message')
       ->markdown('emails.markdown-newPrivateMessage');
}
```

Cordially
````

Comment: What is the issue with receiving 60 emails to notify them of 60 new messages?

Comment: Imagine posting a new message at 2 p.m. and from 2 p.m. to 3 p.m. there are 60 new messages. This means that you will receive 60 emails in 1 hour. That's a lot (60 emails for 1 person in 1 hour). So I would like to know if there is to send only one email that the next one is in 1 hour if there is a new message.

Comment: Well you could add a column to a table that stores the last time an email was sent out for a specific event type (private message) and before you actually send an email, you’d check to see if that time was within your threshold (60 mins) and if so, don’t send an email notification, otherwise send it.

Comment: You can create a `decay` feature. For example, an user received first message at 2 p.m, the mail scheduler will set a decay of 20 mins: If from 2 p.m to 2:20 p.m there is no new message AND the message is not read yet, the mail scheduler will sent the email. If in that range there is an message arrived at 2:15pm, the mail scheduler will refresh deliver time to 2:35PM and notify BOTH message to the user in one email. It's not difficult you can write the mail scheduler by yourself tho.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Your solution Savlon was already an idea I had, it was my last option. About yours Huy Pham, I have never done this. Do you have some documentation or example please ? If not, I'll check myself ;) Thanks both of you !